# Is it OK to keep saying ありがとう

Tags: set-phrases, politeness, culture

I was asking a Japanese person for some help and noticed that I kept saying `ありがとうございます` over and over as they helped me more. Culturally, is it OK to keep saying it multiple times in Japanese? Would it be better to switch to another word to express my gratefulness?

I'm not trying to be English-centric, but I feel like continuously thanking someone might be a little odd or distant in English. I don't feel exactly the same way about it in Japanese, but I want to know what the Japanese perspective is on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess It's ok.
After asking many questions, I keep saying ありがとうございます but I usually add 何度もすみません to convey that I know I am asking a lot and I am sorry for this.